# How to assign the value in a div to a variable using jquery

Tags: jquery, syntax, variable-assignment

I know there's a simple answer to this. I'm trying to assign the value of the div "#loadN" to my index variable "n". If I hardcode a value for n it indexes properly, so I know that's not the problem. I just can't figure out how to assign n the value of the div. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loadN").load("files/user01.profile.txt #year");
    var n = $("#loadN").val();
    $("#listYear option").eq(n).attr('selected','selected')
});


**files/user01.profile.txt**
<div id='year'>3</div>
```

Comment: You didn't let us know what #loadN even is, but I'm pretty sure you're looking for `.html()` rather than `val()`

Comment: and of course, the major problem is that you need to wait on the html load.

Comment: So I'm pulling in the content of the div #year (which exists in an external .txt file - my attempt was to display it at the bottom of the grey box) into the div #loadN.  Now I want to assign the value of #loadN, which in this case happens to be 3, into the variable n. That's the part I'm having problems with.

Comment: My answer does exactly that. Did you not look at it? I gave you the live demo and all.. Also, `#loadN` surely isn't an input element since you're attempting to load other html into it and therefore doesn't have a value. Input elements have values. I believe you're saying you want the contents of `#loadN`, not the value. The contents on `#loadN` is `<div id='year'>3</div>` since that's what you're loading into it. The contents of that is `3`. As you can see in my answer, I have `n` set to the number it found in the loaded file `3`.

Comment: Gotcha, I'm a rookie so sorry I didn't get it at first. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $loadN = $('#loadN'); //cache this so you don't have to keep searching the dom for it
    $loadN.load("mystuff.html", function() { //callback function for the load
      var n = $loadN.children().text(); //now you can access the new contents of the element
      console.log(n);
    });
});
```

[Live demo here (click)](http://plnkr.co/edit/UqzxtxwW4gynrvfcVBFx?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

.val() retrieves information from the "value" attribute of an element:

```
<input type="button" value="Click me">
```

.html() will load the html content of an element (including tags, etc.) so:

```
var n = $("#text").html();
<div id="text">Hello</div>

n = "hello"

var n = $("#text").html();
<div id="text"><span>Hello</span><img src="picture.jpg"></div>

n = "<span>Hello</span><img src="picture.jpg">"
```

Edit: m59 does it the safest way in his example using just the .text() selector; Hope this helps clear up any confusion =D

Comment: If you felt the need to expand on my answer, an edit or a comment would be nice. You didn't deal with the other major problem posed by the question in that he is trying to get the contents of something that hasn't loaded yet. Your answer is only going to distract from my complete solution.